# Как нарисовать следующий график Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, в столбце индексов даты в течение нескольких лет, с частотой в секунду. Нужно построить график средних значений за каждый месяц, т.е на оси *X* лежат даты с частотой в месяц, на оси *Y* - средние значения столбца **value** за каждый месяц. Как это можно сделать (тип графика любой, желательно чтобы было наглядно)

```
                      value
2018-01-01 00:00:00    17.3
2018-01-01 00:00:01    2.01
2018-01-01 00:00:02    31.2
...
2020-01-01 00:00:00    21.3
```

Иначе говоря, нужно посчитать средние значения за каждый месяц и построить график. Пробовал вот так посчитать отдельно периоды для *X* оси.

```
periods = df.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Получение средних за месяц:

```
df.resample('M').mean()
```